# Azcopy failed on Linux Openwrt (Bad function name)

Tags: azure, upload, azure-blob-storage, openwrt

I need to upload file to Azure blobs on my linux device(OS: OpenWrt), I followed the instruction on the Microsoft Azure documents([https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json)), but it returned "syntax error: bad function name"

[image: Execute Azcopy return error]

I wonder that whether the azcopy not support for the OpenWrt. If yes, is there another way to perform upload files to azure blobs? Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that is support.  But Azcopy is an open source project, the best way to specific and accurate answer to questions like yours is to asking contributors of the project.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I also asked the Mircrosoft tech support. He said the Openwrt is not on the support linux version.